# Decoding a Huffman code with a dictionary

Tags: python, huffman-code

I need to decode a Huffman code I coded with my program using a file containing the translation beetween ASCII and Huffman bits. I have already a dictionary in the progam from "codes" to ASCII like this one:

```
{'01110': '!', '01111': 'B', '10100': 'l', '10110': 'q', '10111': 'y'}
```

I created the function:

```
def huffmanDecode (dictionary, text) :
```

That needs the dictionary and the code. I have tried searching the text for key in the dictionary and using both the *replace* method form *string* and the *sub* from *re* but neither of them decodes the message properly.
for example if the code is:

```
011111011101110
```

It should be straightforward to decode it to:

```
By!
```

But I haven't been able to do it by iterating over the code and searching matches in the dictionary!

How can I decode the code using the keys and their values in the dictionary by finding the key inside the text and replacing it by its value?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show your decoding code then. Manually: `011111011101110` -> `01111` = B, `10111` = y, and `01110` = !, all correct according to your own table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure what you tried, but `re.sub` or `replace` probably did not work because they do not necessarily replace from the beginning of the string. You have to see what code the string starts with, then replace that code, and proceed with the rest of the string.

For example, like this:

```
def huffmanDecode (dictionary, text):
    res = ""
    while text:
        for k in dictionary:
            if text.startswith(k):
                res += dictionary[k]
                text = text[len(k):]
    return res
```

Or recursively:

```
def huffmanDecode (dictionary, text):
    if text:
        k = next(k for k in dictionary if text.startswith(k))
        return dictionary[k] + huffmanDecode(dictionary, text[len(k):])
    return ""
```

You could also make a regex from your codes and use `re.match` to find the next one:

```
import re
def huffmanDecode (dictionary, text):
    p = "|".join(dictionary) # join keys to regex
    res = ""
    while text:
        m = re.match(p, text)
        res += dictionary[m.group()]
        text = text[len(m.group()):]
    return res
```

Note: Neither of those have proper error handling and will fail or loop forever if the codes do not match the message, but this should get you started.

Comment: THANKKKKK YOUUUUU!!!! 
You're a life saver man! I had been working in this since Friday and could not figure it out!
You were right my logic with replace was not appropriate, the key was searching from the beginning.

Answer (score 10):

using the [`bitarray`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray/) module you get huffman en-/de-coding for free and probably more efficient than anything else:

```
from bitarray import bitarray

huffman_dict = {
    '!': bitarray('01110'), 'B': bitarray('01111'),
    'l': bitarray('10100'), 'q': bitarray('10110'),
    'y': bitarray('10111')
}

a = bitarray()
a.encode(huffman_dict, 'Bylly!')
print(a)

dec = bitarray('011111011101110').decode(huffman_dict)
print(dec)
print(''.join(dec))

# # output:
# bitarray('011111011110100101001011101110')
# ['B', 'y', '!']
# By!
```

if you do not want to install the module, read the part below.

---

here is a variant using the *huffman tree* to decode - the program works but there may be better variants to represent a binary tree (i chose a tuple).

this version may be better suited when your codewords are not all of the same length. the other nice thing about the binary tree is that here it is obvious that the code is prefix-free.

your code in tree-form looks like this (overly indented in order to make the tree-structure visible):

```
huffman_tree = \
    (   # 0
        (   # 00
            None,
            # 01
            (   # 010
                None,
                # 011
                (   # 0110
                    None,
                    # 0111
                    (   # 01110
                        '!',
                        # 01111
                        'B')))),
        # 1
        (   # 10
            (   # 100
                None,
                # 101
                (   # 1010
                    (   # 10100
                        'l',
                        # 10101
                        None
                    ),
                    # 1011
                    (   # 10110
                        'q',
                        # 10111
                        'y'))),
            # 11
            None))
```

using that you can then decode with:

```
def huffman_decode(strg):
    ret = ''
    cur_node = huffman_tree
    for char in strg:
        cur_node = cur_node[int(char)]
        if cur_node is None:
            raise ValueError
        elif isinstance(cur_node, str):
            ret += cur_node
            cur_node = huffman_tree
    return ret

print(huffman_decode('011111011101110'))
```

if the decoding hits `None` some error occurred and `ValueError` is raised. as soon as the decoding hits a string, the current node `cur_node` is reset to the 'root node' and the game begins from the beginning of the tree.

and just because i can: here is a visual display of your (incomplete) huffman tree (this may  help understand what the algorithm does: whenever you encounter a `0`: go right+down; whenever you encounter a `1`: go right+up); if you hit an end-node: return the character at that node and restart at the root node.
[image: binary huffman tree]

Comment: Nice, learned something new. But why do you thing the `re.match`/`startswith` approach does not work for variable length bit sequences? Seems to work fine for me. Isn't the idea behind huffman codes that no code is a prefix of another?

Comment: @tobias_k sure, the prefixes are all different. but if you have transmission errors (and a huffman code that allows re-syncing) i found the tree approach more suited. but you are right: deleted the 'regex not suited' part from my answer... did not consider efficiency though. did you?