# How to decode prefix codes efficiently with Python?

Tags: python, performance, decoding, prefix, huffman-code

I am trying to decode a Huffman encoded string, with the following script:

```
def decode(input_string, lookup_table):
    codes = lookup_table.keys()
    result = bytearray()

    i = 0
    while len(input_string[i:]) != 0:
        for code in codes:
            if input_string[i:].startswith(code):
                result.append(lookup_table[code])
                i += len(code)
                break

    return ''.join((chr(x) for x in result))

lookup_table = {'10': 108, '00': 111, '0111': 114, '010': 119, '0110': 72, '1111': 33, '1110': 32, '1100': 100, '1101': 101}
input_string = '0110110110100011100100001111011001111'

print decode(input_string, lookup_table)
```

This script gives as output:

```
'Hello world!'
```

The script works for this small string, but decoding an encoded version of [Hamlet](http://erdani.com/tdpl/hamlet.txt) takes 110 seconds. Is there a more efficient and faster way to do this?

Comment: Hi! :) Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/33090486/1707015 help? Is this a duplicate?

Comment: @qräbnö yes, thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decoding a Huffman code with a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33089660/decoding-a-huffman-code-with-a-dictionary)